# How to do exact word parsing with ANTLR4?

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, antlr4

I have the following grammar

```html
grammar test;

expression : SALUTATION NAME;

SALUTATION:'Hello'; 
NAME: ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+;
```

If I have an input string like

1. Hello John
2. Hello John.
3. Hello John Smith

All these strings will be parsed correctly by that grammar

How to modify the grammar to make it parse only strings with the exact defined grammar as in example 1 and fail in other cases like example 2 and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
expression : SALUTATION NAME EOF;
```

Adding `EOF` will force the parser to try to match the `EOF` (end of file) token that's automatically inserted at the end of the token stream. so it'll fail if you have additional data at the end.

You could also add the following lexer rule at the very end of the file:

```
UNKNOWN_CHAR: . ;
```

This will ensure the lexer always succeeds, and all errors will occur in the parser.